# otel-cli: Configuring for local tempo instance

Tags: open-telemetry-collector

My understanding of whole OTEL pipeline setup is that an app(configured with standard OTEL instrumentation agents) emits traces, logs or other metrics, which are send to a collector(again a standard OTEL component), which then processes(formatting etc) these metrics and route them to appropriate platforms, like traces may go to tempo etc.

I have a local grafana tempo instance running in docker. I want to test some of its behaviour. So I need to send traces to it. I may launch a basic app of my own and configure it with required OTEL agents. Another approach can be to use some open source tool.

I cam across one such [cli tool](https://github.com/equinix-labs/otel-cli).

Github page explains the commands I need to execute. But I don't see how I can configure it to send traces to my running tempo instance.

Any input on it would be helpful?